# sys.path modification not working for python2 but works for python3

Tags: python

I am trying to import a module `foo.foo` within the script `'main/main.py'`.

Here is the directory structure:

```
chenjiasheng@ubuntu:~/code/test$ pwd
/home/chenjiasheng/code/test
chenjiasheng@ubuntu:~/code/test$ find
.
./foo
./foo/foo.py
./main
./main/main.py
```

And the content of the two files is:

```
chenjiasheng@ubuntu:~/code/test$ cat ./foo/foo.py 
pass
chenjiasheng@ubuntu:~/code/test$ cat ./main/main.py 
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/chenjiasheng/code/test')
print(sys.path)
import foo.foo
```

'main/main.py' is supposed to append 'foo/' to its module search path.
But running it with python2 gives `ImportError`:

```
chenjiasheng@ubuntu:~/code/test$ python2 main/main.py 
['/home/chenjiasheng/code/test/main', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linues', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/home/chenjiasheng/code/test']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import foo.foo
ImportError: No module named foo.foo
```

In contrast, running it with python3 is OK:

```
chenjiasheng@ubuntu:~/code/test$ python3 main/main.py 
['/home/chenjiasheng/code/test/main', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linu
chenjiasheng@ubuntu:~/code/test$
```

According to the manual, https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path, the `sys.path` variable should work for python2 as well as for python3.

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your `foo` package doesn't have an `__init__.py` file to identify it as a package. Under Python 3 this can still be imported as part of a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), but this feature isn't backported to Python 2. Adding an empty `__init__.py` should mean you can also import that package in Python 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have been more careful when reading the tutorial as a beginner.